# iOS UILongPressGesture working flawlessly on simulator but not on Device

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

I have created a button and added a long press gesture to it, It works flawlessly on simulator, iOS 6 and below devices while on iOS 7 devices it doesn't get called sometimes..

Here is the code that generates the button and gesture recognizer

```
_gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                         initWithTarget:self
                                         action:@selector(myButtonLongPressed:)];
_gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0;
_gesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;

CGRect rect = textView.frame;
tapToRecordBtn = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width-5, rect.size.height)];
tapToRecordBtn.tag = 23;
[tapToRecordBtn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[tapToRecordBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tapToRecordBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[tapToRecordBtn setTitle:@"Hold to Talk" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tapToRecordBtn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"talk-button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[tapToRecordBtn addGestureRecognizer:_gesture];
[containerView addSubview:tapToRecordBtn];
```

This is the method to be called by gesture..

```
-(void) myButtonLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        NSLog(@"gesture Began");   
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        NSLog(@"gesture changed");
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        NSLog(@"gesture End");
    }
}
```

This is really a big trouble solving for me…

Comment: Minimum duration is 0? Try 1 and see if any change. Also, it's easy to hold an absolute position with the mouse in the simulator - try slightly wiggling it to mimic how a real finger press works and see if there is any difference (some other g.r. is active).

Comment: It works on my device...

Comment: @KudoCC It sometimes works on my device too.. the thing is that it calls **gesture Began** after 2 3 seconds

Comment: @DavidH ok i'll try setting the minimum duration and let you know

Comment: I think @DavidH is right, just have a try.

Comment: actually the scenario em implementing is click and hold button to record.. the user is to click and as the user clicks on exact moment  i have to display a uiview.. for this i had used a longpressgesture that is when the user will click, `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` will be called, i display the uiview there and start the recording and when the user picks up the finger it would hide the view as well as stop the recording… any better idea to implement this?

Comment: so for making the user experience i set the minimum duration to 0..

Comment: For your scenario, could you not just wire up the `Touch Down` and `Touch Up Inside` IBActions for the button (ie no gesture recognizer).  Display the UIView on `TouchDown` and hide/stop on `TouchUp`??

Comment: @SoOverIt I did that before this but i have another requirement of click on button and dragging your finger up to cancel it (like in we chat voice message).. how would i do that..?

Comment: How are you implementing the dragging of the finger at the moment?

Comment: @SoOverIt a variable `_initialTouchPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.view]` in Gesture Began,  `CGPoint draggedToPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.view];` in Gesture Changed, difference between shows how much the finger has dragged `_initialTouchPoint.y - draggedToPoint.y`

Comment: What about wiring up the `Touch Drag Inside` and then getting the touch point on in the sent event and compare?? (Touch Drag Inside will still fire even when the finger is dragged outside the button).

Comment: i need to change the view in middle of the drag… i can do this if i had to keep just one view displayed at click..

Comment: Or .. if the pan gesture recogniser is working (i.e., just the long press recogniser giving you grief) .. keep the pan gesture recogniser and use touch up and touch down.

Comment: Ok seems a good idea.. I'll try this  out and let you know..